# Display and change ObservableCollection<>

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, observablecollection

I want to be able to display and change the values of `ObservableCollection<>` in UI. Does it possible? I display it with `ListView` but I can't change them.

Comment: What does "change" mean? What have you tried? How is it not working?

Comment: I mean let user the option to change. like textbox

Comment: What type does the collection contain?

Comment: It contains strings and integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `DataGrid` instead of a `ListView`. `DataGrid` allows cell edition.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. But there is a slight trick involved. 
[Have a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741326/editable-wpf-listbox)

Also, consider using `GridView` for editing